# How to ignore routes in MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing a very simple SPA style application and I don't want to use razor, so I just need it to serve up HTML files (from the wwwroot folder), except for when the js calls my API controllers. In Web API 2 you could get the router to ignore HTML files so they are served directly e.g.

```
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Html", "{whatever}.html/{*pathInfo}");
```

similar to this example: http://www.strathweb.com/2014/04/ignoring-routes-asp-net-web-api/ is the IgnoreRoute functionality just not implemented or has it been changed?

At the moment if I have app.UseMvc(); in my Startup.cs any get request to "/" gets me this exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following     locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful()
```

But when I leave it without MVC it serves up the index.html file when you request "/" - obviously my API controllers won't work then though.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by When comment out the app.UseMvc() it works fine but then the web api won't work of course ? Can you please give some example code over here.

Comment: in my wwwroot folder I have an index.html file, if I disable MVC any request to / serves up the html file, if I enable MVC in my app requests to / result in this exception: InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml.

Comment: So you want that Index.html should serve even when MVC is enable.right ? As per my thinking It has nothing to do with your issue because if you host site in IIS and make index.html as default page then it is going to serve.

Comment: Just updated the question, in IIS  express and VS2015 CTP5 it's still showing the same error.

Comment: Check my answer. Hopefully it solve your problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think if you want to serve index.html even when your MVC option is enabled? If so you have to change one setting.

When you enable MVC there is a default route added to search for Home/Index when your url is like `http://localhost:yourport`.

When you disable MVC it will serve index.html as no route is present in that case.

So if you want to serve index.html when MVC is enabled then add the following in Configure function before using MVC.

```
app.UseDefaultFiles(new Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesOptions() { DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" } });
// your UseMVC goes here.
```

Comment: This works perfectly! That's a very different way of fixing it compared to in Web API 2.0, interesting.

Comment: IgnoreRoute is not available yet. It will come online at some point in the near future, so it will work without the static files middleware. Of course there is nothing wrong with using it, just keep in mind that the functionality is not gone, just not implemented yet,

Comment: Order is super important. For the above to work, I used this order.
`app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles(); app.UseMvc();`

Answer (score 14):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me with the latest current version of MVC 6 (9/5/2015)

Comment: I needed to add package Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles  ( Thanks Resharper!)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me in MVC 6 with .NET Core RC2.  Is there a .NET Core RC2 version?

Comment: This is what I needed when the accepted answer didn't work!